# jquery access to element after append by variable as id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Via ajax i retrieve some json data, make it as html and append it to my page.
Here I have a problem. I cant access element by `id`, if `id` is variable.

For example, http://jsfiddle.net/f8g5e/1/

```
<div id="123">Hello</div>
<div id="321">Bye</div>
<div id="out"></div>

$(function(){
   key = '123';
   $('#' + key).hide();
   $('#321').hide();
});
```

The simples thing is works! `#123` and `#321` elements are hidden. Yeah, it's pretty obviosly.

But, in my project, when I append data to page:

```
$('#123') //returns element
$('#' + key) //returns null
```

Some code:

```
// generating data
var htmlData = '<div id="123">Greetings!</div><div id="321">Bye bye</div>';

// appending data   
$('#tweets').empty();
$('#tweets').append(htmlData);
```

What are the possible causes i can't access elements?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Dont know how it works in JSFiddle, but when I changed my IDs to properly names it began to work now. Thanks to all! Next time, I'll take more attention to w3c dom standarts ;) Happy New Year!

Comment: The only reason I can think of that `$('#'+key)` wouldn't work is because `key` is undefined.

Comment: +1 @mblase75 or not the value expected so alert `key` first to confirm.

Comment: i'm sure, that `key` is defined. even if i add `var key='123';`

Comment: A jsFiddle for the non-working code would be more helpful than one for behaves-as-expected code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can think of that `$('#'+key)` wouldn't work is because the variable `key` is undefined.

Note: you're not supposed to start an ID with a number according to the W3C spec. However, most browsers allow it, so I doubt this is causing your problem.

However, if you have two `div`s with the same ID attribute, then JavaScript will only select the first one it finds -- IDs are supposed to be unique. If this is happening, use classes instead.

Comment: As of HTML5, we are now allowed to start IDs with numerals: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute See [here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) for more details.

Comment: `key` is defined. I changed my IDs from pure numbers to something like `element%D` where `%d` is key - no changes

Comment: Debug your code by adding `alert(key);` and `alert($('#'+key).length);` just before the problem part of your code. `$('#'+key)` should never actually be null.

Comment: `console.log(key);` before accessing to element printed keys needed.

Comment: "Keys", plural? It's not a simple string?

Answer (score -1):

You can either do this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#321,#123').hide();
});
```

or you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  var key = '123';
  var doit = '321';
  $('#' + key + ',#' + doit).hide();
});
```